# there is a way to show my png ? because in my example its give me just grey item and not rounded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

is there a way to show my png? it gives an error that nothing was returned from render, the return is missing.
what should I do to fix it? 
this is my example of the code that I try to show 2 png next to each other but it give an error.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import HeaderButton from "../components/HeaderButton";
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';



const OrderInformationScreen = props => {
    <View
    style={{
      height: 150,
      //backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }}
  >
    <Avatar
      size='large'
      overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#00BFFF' }}
      containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
      activeOpacity={0.2}
      rounded
      ImageSource={('../assets/down.png')} style={{ height: 120, width: 120, borderRdius: 60 }} 
    />
    <View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Side Menu</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default OrderInformationScreen
```

Answer (score 0):

The error return is missing means you need to return yur jsx to get it rendered.

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from "react-navigation-header-buttons";
import HeaderButton from "../components/HeaderButton";
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';



const OrderInformationScreen = props => {
return(
    <View
    style={{
      height: 150,
      backgroundColor: '#00BFFF',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }}
  >
    <Avatar
      size='large'
      overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#00BFFF' }}
      containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
      activeOpacity={0.2}
      rounded
      source={('../assets/up.png')} style={{ height: 120, width: 120, borderRdius: 60 }} 
    />
    <Avatar
      size='large'
      overlayContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#00BFFF' }}
      containerStyle={{ marginTop: 30 }}
      activeOpacity={0.2}
      rounded
      source={('../assets/down.png')} style={{ height: 120, width: 120, borderRdius: 60 }} 
    />
    <View>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Side Menu</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default OrderInformationScreen
```

Comment: i edit my code above , why its not show me the image ?

Comment: Did you added the return statement?

Answer (score 0):

when you use a arrow function `() => {}` if you use curly braces you should defnitely use return if you want to return directly one item then try and replace `{}` with `()`